# como crear plantillas para blogger?

Tags: html, xml, blogger

Estoy empezando en esto del desarrollo web y quería subir mi pagina a blogger pero me pedia un archivo XML, alguien sabe como puedo hacer para subir lo que hice como plantilla?

o si alguno tiene algun tutorial para crear templates me ayudaria mucho

Comment: Tu pregunta no es correcta, porque está basado en opiniones, y está fuera del reglamento. Aquí resolvemos problemas de códigos, mostrando tu código. Si quieres ayuda sobre Blogger, en su misma página tiene ayuda extenso y tutorial; o busca en YouTube

Comment: Bienvenido, es un poco amplia tu pregunta, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Disculpa, Mala mia